# How to get one column from SQL to excel using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded this macro:

```
    Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Data Source=10.0.10.10;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=" _
        , _
        "True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=PC01;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=ABC"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("""ABC"".""dbo"".""Table""")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table__10.0.10.10_ABC_TABLE"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

How to show only ID field. In current macro I get all records from my SQL table, how to get result:
[image]

Comment: What query are you executing in the macro? post the relevant part of the macro

Comment: I didn't write any query, I even don't know where to add that query. Updating question.

Comment: @pvaitonis It seems that you do not appreciate any of the work people have put into their answers. You've posted ten questions and never accepted any of the answer nor have you ever upvoted any of them. Maybe if you start showing some appreciation people will feel more compelled to look at your questions and post an answer.

Comment: BTW: you are currently using `xlCmdTable` for the [query table command type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840602.aspx). But you can change this to `xlCmdSql`. Then you'd have a query where you could select only one column from the table (instead of all columns from the table). Of course, you'd have to change the `CommandText` to something like `select ItemID from ABC.dbo.Table`.